# Java code signing for spring boot fat jar

Tags: gradle, spring-boot, code-signing

After signing my spring boot fat jar with gradle ant sign task I get the following Exception:

Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes

Whats wrong here? Do I have to sign all the dependent jars too? How can I do that with gradle and the spring-boot plugin?

Comment: To little details to help :/ Does it help: http://jehy.ru/articles/2013/12/13/invalid-signature-file-digest-for-manifest-main-attributes/ ?

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found the solution!

do the signing in

```
build.doLast{
//signing
}
```

and not in

```
jar.doLast{....}
```